# How to split HDMI video and audio? 

Tags: audio, hdmi

I have a single HDMI output cable (from my graphics card, ATI 5750) carrying both HD video & audio.

I connect the cable to the monitor for HD video, but I want to split the HD audio from the HDMI cable & plug it into a 5.1 HTS with an 3 pin analog input.

Do I need some converters/Splitters to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a receiver, most receivers include a HDMI Video out and in.

What I have done with my 5850 is connect a HDMI from the card to my receiver's HDMI IN, and then a HDMI from my receiver's HDMI OUT to my Monitor.

Unfortunately if you don't have a receiver, I don't think there's any other way to get sound to your loud speakers thorough HDMI.

Comment: Thanx for ur suggestion . I don't have any receiver as of now. Can u give me the details regarding what sort of receiver i should buy, the tech specs & the brand...etc.,.

Comment: Just look for an HDMI audio capable receiver, some are expensive but you can pick up a quality one used from many places. I purchased an Onkyo SR605 Used and it's doing great.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit for Final Answer:**
Looks like [this](http://www.gefen.com/kvm/dproduct.jsp?prod_id=8202) might be just what you are looking for. It should be fairly simple to convert the output from it into any wiring type your speakers use. Only drawback is the cost, at $600. Hopefully it's in your budget.

**Original Answer**
You also might look on the back of your TV to see if it has any Audio Out connections. Most TVs sold currently will have at least one type of audio output on them (typically either Digital Coaxial or Optical). Then see if your speakers/receiver have a compatible input.

**EDITed** to include comment in answer
OK. After searching amazon.com for a couple minutes I found the following [adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002WBOQPU). It shouldn't be too hard to convert that into whatever inputs your speaker system has (although it does look like you'd lose any native surround signal). If you need to keep the HDMI video signal for your monitor, then a simple 2 way split before the coverter would do the trick. Something like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0015YRMXI).

Comment: Thanx for the suggestion. But I'm afraid my LCD Monitor does not have any audio OUT. So that option is ruled out. If u know of any other alternate solution, i hope......it would be really helpful.

Comment: ok. after searching amazon.com for a couple minutes i found the following: http://tinyurl.com/2vqljhh :it shouldn't be too hard to convert that into whatever inputs your speaker system has (althought it does look like you'd loose any native surround signal). if you need to keep the HDMI video signal for your monitor then a simple 2 way split before the coverter would do the trick. something like this: http://tinyurl.com/33c7wwc

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar situation.  I have an older receiver that does not take HDMI input, however it is still a great receiver and I dont want to replace it.  The TVs speakers arent that great and no surround sound.

My solution was to use HDMI only for video.  I connected the onboard stereo out to the receiver, and later put in a sound card for optical output (surround sound).  All you have to do is disable audio on your graphics card in the windows sound devices.