# Converting HDMI to RCA - laptop to TV?

Tags: video, connection, hdmi, cable

I'm planning on going to visit parents over christmas and am looking to bring my laptop to be able to play video on my parent's TV.

They've got a big widescreen from the early 2000s which has RCA inputs on the front.

Is it possible for me to play video from my laptop via the HDMI port going into the RCA slot's somehow?

I know there will be a definition difference but is this possible?

If not is there a scart solution for the same thing?

Laptop does also have a VGA slot but as this doesnt tranmit video I'd rather not have to have 2 cables.

Any input greatfully received.

thanks

b

Comment: Not exactly the same question but a similar answer: [HDMI Video/Audio Split](http://superuser.com/questions/204718/hdmi-video-audio-split/204820#204820)

Answer (score 1):

You simply need an HDMI to composite adapter, such as this one: [http://www.amazon.com/ViewHD-Universal-Composite-Converter-Standard/dp/B0080KN18K](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0080KN18K)